# Workflow to count total numeric value in a column and show on a new column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, rest, designer-workflow

Environment: SharePoint 2013 Enterprise

Is it possible to sum the numeric values in a column and show the output on a new column in SharePoint 2013 List using SharePoint Designer Workflow?

List schema and result screenshot for better understanding:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you try with count option of column and than to use rest api to catch that value and put it in new field/column.

Comment: I`m well versed on rest api, any article that gives deeper update  for freshers

Comment: https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible through SPD 2013 workflow along with REST Webservice call. Follow the steps below,

1. Create a list workflow for the list where Column1 is present
2. Configure the workflow to get triggered on Item Adding and Item Edit
3. Edit the workflow
4. Build a dictionary with below parameters and set output variable as Request Header

   `accept : application/json;odata=verbose
   content-Type : application/json;odata=verbose`
5. Call HTTP Web Service with following parameters

   HTTP Web Service URL: `<Site Url>/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('<List Name>')/items?$select=Column1`

   HTTP Method: HTTP GET

   ResponseContent to Variable: data
   In the properties of this action, set RequestHeaders parameter to `Variable: Request Header` created in the step 4
6. Add the below steps

   `Get d/results from Variable: data (Output to Variable: dataList )`

   `Count Items in Variable: dataList (Output to Variable: count1 )`

   `Log Variable: count1 to the workflow history list`

   `Set Variable: index to 0`

   `Set Variable: Sum to 0`
7. Create a loop block with `Loop n Times` then add the following steps into it,

   `The contents of this loop will run Variable: count1 times`

   `Get d/results([%Variable: index%])/Column1 from Variable: data (Output to Variable: Column1Value )`

   `Calculate Variable: Sum plus Variable: Column1Value (Output to Variable: calc1 )`

   `Set Variable: Sum to Variable: calc1`

   `Calculate Variable: index plus 1 (Output to Variable: calc )`

   `Set Variable: index to Variable: calc`
8. Now you will get the summation of Column1, using the below step add/update item in the corresponding list

   `Create item in this list (Output to Variable: create )`

This is the basic logic for your requirement, enhance the code based on your further requirements.

Refer the following links for more informations,

[CALLING THE SHAREPOINT 2013 REST API FROM A SHAREPOINT DESIGNER WORKFLOW](https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)

[Looping Through List Items in SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflows](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Nagarajan, appreciate for such a detailed explanation. Will test n update

Comment: Wecome.. awaiting your response

Comment: Hope this can be reused by making it part site template?  As that is my destination.

Comment: Jason, making a site template and reusing it can be done. But did this worflow gave you the needed solution?

Comment: Give me few hours, as need to access my dev environment to test the same.

Comment: accessing http://test.example.com/projecttemplate/_api/web/Lists/GetbyTitle('Actions')/items


gives error :

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>
-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException
</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
The expression "web/Lists/GetbyTitle('Actions’)/items" is not valid.
</m:message>
</m:error>

Comment: Have you done Web service call using SPD before? Else read the reference link shared. The code i have shared was perfectly working for me. If it is not working in ur side, probably you might have missed something. Getting all item through REST api is very simple url. Check it.

Comment: will update you, once I resolve issue with the rest url and workflow in SPD2013 not showing SPS workflow 2013 option. Thanks for the follow up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41487/discussion-between-nagarajan-muthukumar-and-jason).